How to recompositon the screen when we save data to shared preference in android compose
I have text with first name last name which is empty initially. After making some api call and get first name last name and i will save that in shared preference. Once shared preference saved i want to show that in the screen. below is the code i am trying which is not working. Why recomposition not happening after saving to preference even i am using
remember { mutableStateOf
val preferencesManager = remember { MyPreferenceManager(context) }
    val userFirstName = remember { mutableStateOf(preferencesManager.getPreferenceData(AppPreferencesConstant.USER_FIRST_NAME, AppConstant.BLANK_STRING)) }
    val userLastName = remember { mutableStateOf(preferencesManager.getPreferenceData(AppPreferencesConstant.USER_LAST_NAME, AppConstant.BLANK_STRING)) }


if (userFirstName.value.isEmpty().not) {
                    Text(text = userFirstName.value.)
                }

Once api success i am updating shared preference
preferencesManager.savePreferenceData(
    AppPreferencesConstant.USER_FIRST_NAME,
    "firstname from api"
)
preferencesManager.savePreferenceData(
    AppPreferencesConstant.USER_LAST_NAME,
    "lastname from api"
)


There are two simple ways,
1.update the new value (aka from api request) directly into the variable
var userFirstName by remember { mutableStateOf(preferencesManager.getPreferenceData(AppPreferencesConstant.USER_FIRST_NAME, AppConstant.BLANK_STRING)) }
var userLastName by remember { mutableStateOf(preferencesManager.getPreferenceData(AppPreferencesConstant.USER_LAST_NAME, AppConstant.BLANK_STRING)) }
LaunchedEffect(Unit){
 val firstNameFromApi = fetchData() //whatever your api is
 userFirstName = firstNameFromApi
 }
 

2.if you're using viewmodels for fetching and store data
create a live data inside of the viewmodel and observe in Ui
class viewmodel{
val firstUserName : MutableLiveData<String>  = mutableLiveData(preferencesManager.getPreferenceData(AppPreferencesConstant.USER_FIRST_NAME, AppConstant.BLANK_STRING))
//fetch and update the name using the live data inside of the viewmodel globally 
}

@Composable
fun yourUi(viewModel: ViewModel){
val firstName by viewModel.firstUserName.observerAsState(initial = "")
Text(text = firstName)
 }

